# Open source SMTP gateway

Tags: smtp

I am looking to install a SMTP gateway for our MS Exchange server. I am looking for an open-source (and preferably free) solution that does anti-spam and anti-virus filtering. I am wondering if anyone knows of any thing as I have not been able to find any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't deal with appliances if you are looking for some single distro just for this purpose, then you might have difficulty.  If you go with a general purpose linux, and mail transport agent there are a huge number of possibilities.  I am surprised you couldn't find anything.

Simply install your favorite mail transport agent (exim, postfix, sendmail, whatever), then integrate one of the many anti-spam/malware mechansisms (spamassassion, clamav, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to set up Postfix on a CentOS box:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix

Here's how to hook up Postfix with Amavis with filtering for antivirus and antispam:

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Amavisd

The main difference with this scenario to what you want is that the Postfix instructions are for delivery to a Dovecot IMAP server.  You would have to configure Postfix to send to your Exchange box for final delivery.  Take a look at this:

http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#firewall

for configuration examples for Postfix to act as a gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Untangle should do the job nicely http://www.untangle.com/

However, shopping quuestions are off topic on all stack overflow sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ESVA appliance](http://www.esvacommunity.com/) [VM images](http://www.esvacommunity.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=117&sid=d0a220dd64bed4cf78921266a6374b04#p372) (look towards the bottom for those links).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a really simple, but effective solution, I have used [MailScanner](http://mailscanner.info/) for years.